# Buttons clickable area edit

Tags: html, css

How could I disable right half of this buttons clickable area?
[image: Button]

HTML

```css
.button {
  border-color: #000000;
  border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  transform: rotate(135deg);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="button.css">
</head>

<body>
  <input class="button" type="button" />
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: May I know the reason for this?

Comment: what problem in above code

Comment: Wrap it in a containing element, set its `width` to obscure the section you require disabled and declare `overflow: hidden` - untested but should work.

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError but that would hide the actual half of the button, not only make in unclickable wouldn't it? maybe just put another transparent element over the unclickable half of the button. Also, I agree with Mohammad Usman, why do you want this?

Comment: @Maharkus the intention is to *hide* the part of the button you don't want to have clickable. You could also add a transparent layer with a higher `z-index` but then I would still advise placing it in a containing element wrapping the `input` tag for better control over precise positioning.

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError OP never mentions anything about *hiding* the button, just disabling it or am I missing something?

Comment: If the solution works, then it is worth considering @Maharkus - let's advise and offer suggestions and leave the OP to be the judge of what suits his/her requirements best.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try this (i added a border and a background so we can see that it's only half) :

```css
.button {
  border-color: #000000;
  border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  background:red; /* Remove this background */
  transform: rotate(135deg);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.but {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #000; /* Remove this border later */
  padding: 5px;
  width: 12px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<span class="but">
<input class="button" type="button" />
</span>
```

Comment: This is what I had in mind, thank you for demonstrating @Temani :)

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError welcome ;)  i just notice your debate with maharkus after i was done coding :)

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError by the way the solution of maharkus is almost the same, the difference is if we want or not to show the button, but i think it's logic to hide it, the OP want to have a triangle i am sure

Comment: Yes, it should work in practice as well - this solution is more efficient though, no need for extra nested transparent elements or `pseudo-elements` so I prefer it.